# Security concerns on implementing application network protocol

Tags: c++, network-protocols

Following my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26685441/client-server-message-interpretation/), I'm trying to implement some kind of message-parsing on a server machine.

Currently a message looks like this:

```
int _header_signature; 
int _offset_a; 
int _offset_b; 
int _size_a;
int _size_b; 
wchar_t stuff[_size_a];
wchar_t stuff2[_size_b]; 
int _footer_signature;
```

I could get some code that works, by decoding the header and sizes and to know if I received the whole message or there is more pending. But what stops a malicious user from altering these messages on purpose and crashing my machine? E.g. changing one of the size values or offsets to something larger than my message.

How do I make my server secure and robust against whatever message it receives?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. You have to validate the data  you receive.

Of course you can/should encrypt data sent over the network, to protect against man in the middle attacks, but that doesn't stop someone from just sending you garbage data.

So you'll have to check if the data is garbage. If the offsets point outside the message then something fishy is going on, and you'll have to deal with that.

Comment: Why encrypt data when it is not needed? A lot of it is safe to go unencrypted.

Comment: If the OP doesn't want third parties to modify the data in flight? He seems concerned about malicious parties trying to bring his software down by forging his protocol messages

Comment: @jaif - Or perhaps an error in the network or the code sending it. It may not be malicious.

Comment: Can anyone point me to some example? I've spent 30 minutes writing down examples on paper but I still can't figure out how can I validate the offsets. If I check whether an offset points to some location how do I now it is pointing to the right thing? The location might exist but it might be the wrong one. Also what if two messages may be queued up and it may be large enough to point something on the other message. I'm sorry if I'm confusing but an example or a link to one would really help. Thanks

Comment: @EdHeal you're right, but the OP explicitly talked about malicious users. I'm not saying that encryption alone solves his problem entirely, just that if he is concerned about the data being tampered with in-flight, it's an obvious solution to that part of the problem.

Comment: @Panayiotis when you receive a message, you know its size, right? That means you know the address it begins on, and the address it ends on. So do all the offsets point to addresses that lie between those two points?

Comment: @jalf I seem to be lacking important TCP knowledge. How do I know the size of a message? As far as I'm concerned I'm just receiving data and writing it on to a buffer, is there anything that guarantees the size? (the size message fields can be just as easily manipulated so I don't think they are reliable)

Comment: @Panayiotis that has to be part of your own protocol. TCP doesn't help you with that. You have to figure that out based on the data you receive as part of your message. You can sanity check your size field too (ensure that you've actually received at least as many bytes as the size field says there should be, before you try to process the message), but at the end of the day, you get the data you get, and you have to write code to determine if it looks trustworthy. Yes, network programming is *hard* if you want it to be reliable.

Answer (score -2):

Just serialise the data http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization

and then check that the offsets are valid.

Comment: My data is serialized and sent, but how do I check the offsets? How do I know they are valid?

Comment: Well you know the sizes of the two arrays. Why not just check those values are in limits

Comment: How do I know the sizes of the two arrays? Those values may be manipulated as well. ( I wasn't the one who downvoted in case you are wondering)

Comment: You sent the two values for their size. They read those bytes off the wire to fill them up. If ran out of data it is duff.